# Same sessionid across all open windows?

Tags: php, session, get, remember-me

Is it possible to have the same session be active across multiple open windows in a php app?

I want to have SOME of the convenience of the dreaded "remember me" checkbox type system without the same amount of risk to the user's data.

The specific use case I have run into is this: When a user receives a "friend request", an e-mail is sent to them with a link that contains a random hash and their username in the url. Say the person is already logged in to my service in one window and is checking their mail for the confirmation e-mail in another. They click the link in the confirmation e-mail and it launches a third window which initiates a GET request to the relevant confirmation page. I'd like to make it so that if the user is already logged in to the service in another window and the hash and username match those stored in the "requests" table of my database, clicking the link instantly confirms the friend. However, if they are not already logged in in another window, they are then forced to log in to confirm the friend request.

Currently if a person is logged in in another window, clicking the link launches a third window and the person must log in again regardless of whether they have another open session.

Is this functionality possible without using cookies to maintain a persistent login?

**Update:** This question demonstrates my own lack of understanding regarding how sessions work. The user's session IS normally preserved across concurrently open browser windows by default. The issue, as was addressed in the answer I accepted was that I had one window open with www.example.com as the URL and one with example.com as the URL, in which case a different session is created in the second window rather than continuing the session started in the first window.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier just to use https and secure cookies?

Comment: The behavior you have now is a little off. There is already one session shared between all browser windows, since there's only one cookie holding a session id for your domain and path.

Comment: Not without cookies. At least you need to share the session ID in one place. As it's for all browser tabs/windows, a cookie sounds very fitting. The alternative - session ID query-info parameter is encoded into the URL and is slightly less secure than a cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use cookie-based sessions, the session is already maintained between windows (of the same browser executable).

The session ID is the only client-side stored token in this case, and browsers don't generally segregate cookies between different windows.

You may have an issue in that they're visiting your web site via two different domain names (`www.example.com` vs `example.com` vs `www.example.org`, or the like), but fundamentally there is no problem unless you try to use GET-passed session IDs.

You will technically "use cookies" - but the cookies only hold the session ID, not the session *contents*. If that is anathema to you, you could store the session ID using the HTML5 LocalData API, or with a Flash object, or a Java applet, or whatever...

I strongly advise against attempting to identify the clients *a posteriori* via their IP address or browser characteristics. Just have them store a token, and use that to determine who they are.

Comment: Thank you! I think the problem was that I was accessing the site without a www normally (since it's easier to type) but the link in the confirmation e-mails has a www in it. Is there a way that I can ensure that the user is always redirected to the www. version of the site, even if they type example.com only?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=htaccess+redirect+to+www assuming you use Apache. Substitute htaccess for your http server of choice if not.

Answer (score 0):

A typical login system has sessions and cookies . Cookies are only set if the users wants to be remembered to avoid input hes data again from that spesific browser and nothing else.
Session live while you are loggen but the will be destroyde after you close the window thus prompting for a login again.
 While saving cookies to a users browser it is vital that you encrypte their data .also instead of the password save a cookie with a refrensnumber (ID) and not their password.